# Find where a small 2d matrix exists within a larger 2d matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have the following 6x6 matrix a, and 2x2 matrix b:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])

b = np.array([[0, 1],
              [0, 0]])
```

I want to create a truth table where a smaller array 2d matrix exists inside of the larger one, however only selecting the top-left index

Expected output:

```
>>> array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
           [False, True,  False, True,  False, False],
           [False, False, False, False, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

I suppose I could construct a massive loop and evaluate using np.roll() but I am hoping there's an elegant solution instead?

Comment: Is the input always a binary array with 0s and 1s?

Comment: I wanted to keep the problem simple for stack overflow, but the real array is an RGB image matrix (10,10,3), so each location will actually be a list. @Divakar

Comment: Your input array `a` has shape `(6, 6)` and apparently you expect your output array to be of the same shape. How is that possible? How are you going to compare `a` with `b` at the position `a[5, 5]`? Usually you can only compare up to `a[4, 4]` and then your output array will have shape `(5, 5)`. Could you clarify?

Comment: You've exposed an important assumption. I would like to pad the bottom row with a copy of the top row.

Comment: @DanielScott Please see my updated answer for additional padding.

Comment: @a_guest Excellent update. Thanks for the great answer. If searching for a 3x3 matrix within a 5000x5000 matrix, your method takes ~6 seconds. This appears to be about 3x faster than iterating through the 5000x5000 matrix and individually checking each neighbor.

Comment: @a_guest Your answer is vectorized so i'm puzzled why it's not much faster than iterating?

Comment: @DanielScott I checked the timings for your parameters and I got a speedup factor of about 48. How did you do the manual iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) to create a version of `a` with two additional dimensions that serve for the comparison. Then you can use `.all(axis=(-2, -1))` in order to verify the equality:

```
In [3]: a2 = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=a.shape + b.shape, strides=2*a.strides)
In [4]: a2 = a2[:-b.shape[0]+1, :-b.shape[1]+1]
In [5]: (a2 == b).all(axis=(-2, -1))                                                          
Out[5]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

If you want additional padding you can use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) beforehand:

```
a = np.pad(a, ((0, 1), (0, 1)), mode='wrap')
```

Then proceed as above with `as_strided`.

Comment: Yes I see you slice it afterwards. Just setting the right shape in `as_strided` seems simpler though

Comment: @yatu could you provide an example?